# How to solve Php 7 not found Sqlite3?

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS. I had php5 on that OS. I used Sqlite3 in one script and I could run it from cli easily.

No after upgrade it is php7 which runs for cli => /etc/php/7.0/cli

But it cannot detect the SQLite3, and I get 'PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SQLite3' not found' error.

I tried to install it again with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

But it says it is installed now.

How can I solve this problem that php7 could detect SQLite3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3`

Comment: If you need another php7 extensions, use `sudo apt-cache search php7-* ` to find it's names.

Comment: You might need to re-accept the correct answer

Comment: @T.Todua I think I accepted the correct answer.

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari  just the "without version" php installation seemed better. anyway, ok

Answer (score 19, accepted):

sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3

Comment: change 7.0 to the appropriate version if necessary, e.g 7.2

Comment: Below answer is better

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt install php-sqlite3
```

This worked for me and installed php7.0-sqlite3 and setup the config files.

This is for Ubuntu 16.04 and higher.

Comment: Thank you! Seems I needed `php7.2-sqlite3`, which this command installed, and specifying 7.0 as in the accepted answer was no good.